# CKeditor instance is null or undefined?

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

Hi all i have an CKeditor in my screen ckeditor is displaying but when i try to get the instance of the editor i have the value null or undefined how can i get the ckeditor instance can any one help me here

```
function editor() {
    //i have null here
    for (name in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        CKEDITOR.instances[name].destroy()
    }

    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;//i have null here
    editor.on('key', function () {
        var data = editor.getData();        
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {    
    var editorShort = CKEDITOR.editor.replace('popup_editor1');
    editor();
});
```

Answer (score 6):

It could be that the instances variable is simply undefined at that time. Depending on what you really want to do with the editor, I suggest that you do the on key bindings and other such things inside instanceReady, which is a CKEditor event.

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
    // You can define it before replacing the editor
    CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(e){
        // Do your bindings / other actions here
        // To access the editor that this event has fired on:
        const editor = e.editor;
    });

   // replace editor
    const editorVar = CKEDITOR.editor.replace('popup_editor1');
});
```

See the documentation at http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-event-instanceReady

---

Or if you don't use jQuery

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    // You can define it before replacing the editor
    CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(e){
        // Do your bindings / other actions here
        // To access the editor that this event has fired on:
        const editor = e.editor;
    });

   // replace editor
    const editorVar = CKEDITOR.editor.replace('popup_editor1');
});
```

Comment: I have used this approach to add the paste listener into the editor, as described here: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_clipboard.html . I have tried several methods in an attempt to get this to work, and this is the only one that does.

Answer (score 0):

Nenotlep answer was fine ,I am just adding on something to help those like me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { 
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(evt){
  console.log("instance is ready");
  for (var instance in CKEDITOR.instances)
            CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
```

// now if you do console.log(instance) it will give editor or id_your_editor ,,use this value

```
  var slug= $('#slugfield').val()
  var e=CKEDITOR.instances.id_Your_Message
  e.on('keyup', function(e){
  var content = CKEDITOR.instances[instance].getData()
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "{% url 'edit-update' %}",
      data: {'slug':newslug,'code':content},
      success: function (data) {
        console.log("instance is");
        console.log(instance);
      },
      error: function(data) {
          console.log("error");
      }
  });

});
});
});
</script>
```