# CKEDITOR get instance doesnt working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ckeditor

I have a ckeditor object and i want to insert text current position. So i try to get ckeditor object but page returns error. My ckeditor version is 3.6.4

ASPX:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="CKEditor.NET" Namespace="CKEditor.NET" TagPrefix="CKEditor" %>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

    <CKEditor:CKEditorControl Width="100%" BasePath="~/Controls/Base/ckeditor" CssClass="AutoCompColumnList" ID="txtMessageBody" Height="500px" runat="server"
    </CKEditor:CKEditorControl>

    </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I tried this:

CKEDITOR.instances.txtMessageBody.insertText('some text here');

Error:

CKEDITOR is not defined!

Comment: That error means either that your CKEditor is not loaded (yet) or it totally failed to load. In the first case, make sure the order of execution is right, in the second one check if the resource is loaded at all.

Comment: i add ckeditor to add reference project. I already use normally ckeditor on page. But i cant access it on javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CKeditor instance is null or undefined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867346/ckeditor-instance-is-null-or-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

I tried using CKEditor recently but gave up because it seemed to take a long time to get on the page and because it kept adding carriage returns in side the html. To get rid of that I had to write this:

```
var editor;
function changeEnter()
{
if (editor)
    editor.destroy(true);

editor = CKEDITOR.replace('CKEditor1',
{
on:
{
instanceReady: function (ev)
{
//output paragraphs as <p>Text</p>
this.dataProcessor.write.setRules('p',
{
indent: false,
breakBeforeOpen: true
});
}
}
});
window.onload = changeEnter;
```

I took all that from one of their sample pages. I don't really know what it does, but it works. Before putting that on the page I kept getting CKEditor is not defined messages.

Sorry, can't be bothered to indent the code. Why is it so hard to post code on this site. It sets itself up as the pre-eminent software forum - yet the way you have to write code is awful. Why no [code] tags like you get on other sites?