# Error: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null (ckeditor)

Tags: javascript, laravel, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, ckeditor5

I am making Laravel CMS with ckeditor.
When I write some html code in ckeditor source code mode status, I got some error as follows;

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null
    at Widget.init (plugin.js?t=H0CG:366)
    at new Widget (plugin.js?t=H0CG:967)
    at Repository.initOn (plugin.js?t=H0CG:498)
    at Repository.initOnAll (plugin.js?t=H0CG:535)
    at a.<anonymous> (plugin.js?t=H0CG:2816)
    at a.p (ckeditor.js:10)
    at a.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:12)
    at a.CKEDITOR.editor.CKEDITOR.editor.fire (ckeditor.js:13)
    at ckeditor.js:877
```

And the status of source code editing is unenabled.
This page has somewhat much contents including about 200 ~ 250 words and 15 images.
In my thought, are there some limitation of ckeditor contents?

Comment: Is the instance properly created? You may want to check this answer.

[https://stackoverflow.com/a/15871772/1348003](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15871772/1348003)

Comment: My site has several pages, but above case happened in only 2 pages with somewhat much contents.

Comment: Try to observe the console for any error the ckeditor throws during initialization. This error is because the ckeditor instance has not initialized or maybe somehow replaced with null.

Answer (score 0):

I had same error After so many attempts [this](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/6071#issuecomment-866209780) helped me fix the problem

just needed the webpack rule like this:

```
const filesRuleIndex = cfg.module.rules.findIndex(item => {
  return item.test.test('.svg')
})

if (filesRuleIndex !== -1) {
  cfg.module.rules[filesRuleIndex].test = /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|webp)$/
  const svgRule = {...cfg.module.rules[filesRuleIndex]}
  svgRule.test = /\.svg/
  svgRule.exclude = svgRule.exclude || []
  svgRule.exclude.push(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', '@ckeditor'))
  cfg.module.rules.push(svgRule)
}

cfg.module.rules.push({
  test: /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\]icons[/\\][^/\\]+\.svg$/,
  use: ["raw-loader"]
})
```